# Working with ngClass inside ngRepeat and Foundation framework

Tags: html, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I've found that my ng-class is overwritten when used inside an ng-repeat by the Foundation framework that I'm using. The code is relatively simple:

```
<tr ng-repeat="goal in goals" ng-class="goal.difficulty">
```

I can see the class being applied in chrome dev tools, but it is overwritten by the tables.scss styles of

```
tables tr:nth-of-type(even)
```

I have **my** CSS after the foundation one, so I'm somewhat at a loss as to how this happens.

**Edit:**

Since people don't believe it's being overwritten here is an image (you can also check out the project from Github)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1G5.jpg

https://github.com/OrganicCat/goal-tracker

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting !important at the end of your class style definitions so that they override foundation.

That is not a solution, but it indicates that your styling is clashing with zurb. The correct answer then would be to remove the default table styling from zurb using sass, in particular:

```
// These control the background color for the table and even rows
$table-bg: $white;
$table-even-row-bg: $snow;
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tables.html

I do not believe the class is not being applied to the element (unless you post up some rendered html showing otherwise).

Comment: I've never had someone not "believe" a problem I'm having, so sure, I posted an image of the rendered page with chrome tools showing the ".Pirate" class is being overwritten as I said. I also posted the github repo in case you wanted to try it out.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a confusion of wording. The class isn't being overwritten, but its properties are. So yeah !important will work or writing the class out of the scss. There probably isn't a neater solution, it's weird that zurb doesn't let you turn off basic styling stuff like that without modifying the base files.